# How to animate layout from top to 300dp of screen vice versa in android?

Tags: android, animation, slide

### Requirement

I can translate layout base on `toYDelta="100%` or `toYDelta="50%` etc.

But I want to animate layout only in `300dp Height`.

### slide_down.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

### slide_up.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

### Java Code (Animation)

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_down);
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // I can hide layout after animation completion 

    }
});
```

### Mockup

[image: Animation Mockup]

### Problem

How to do base on 300dp height?

Please help me for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## View Animation

Surprisingly enough, there does not seem to be a way to specify a 300dp translate animation in XML. The translate animation [XML syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View) accepts three different distance specifications:

- Absolute pixels relative to normal position (e.g. `android:toYDelta="10"`)
- Percentage relative to element width/height (e.g. `android:toYDelta="10%"`)
- Percentage relative to parent width/height (e.g. `android:toYDelta="10%p"`)

You are also restrained to the same specifications when you create a `TranslateAnimation` [via Java](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html). However, in Java you can calculate the equivalent absolute pixel value (for a given device) and supply that as your pixel translate distance.

To get 300dp, you can either define a [dimen value](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) of 300dp in XML, or simply perform the calculation in code.

Inside `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="distance">300dp</dimen>
```

Inside your Activity/Fragment/etc:

```
float distance = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.distance);
```

**OR**

Inside your Activity/Fragment/etc:

```
float distance = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300,
        getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
);
```

Then all you need to do is use that distance when creating your `TranslateAnimation`:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, distance
);
```

## Property Animation

If you are targeting Android 3.0 and above, you can use the new [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) framework to express the same animation more elegantly:

```
view.animate().translationY(distance).setDuration(...).start();
```

If you are still targeting Android 2.x, you can use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) to get backwards compatible animation syntax. It will automatically use the new property animations for devices that support it.

```
ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(view).translationY(distance).setDuration(...).start();
```

Comment: @Darshak please award the bounty :)